# Controlling when to close OkHttpClient3 using java

Tags: java, okhttp

when I set okhttpClient3 I am sending a get request like following:

```
public String sendGetRequest(String url, HashMap<String, String> headersMap) throws Exception {

        Headers headers = addHeaders(headersMap);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url).headers(headers).build();
        try{
            Response response =httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            LOG.info(String.format("Response data is: =[%s]", response.body().string()));
            return response.body().string();
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOG.error(String.format("Request failed=[%s]",e.getMessage()));

        }finally {
            httpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I see that when I am trying to return the string response I am getting that the client was closed.
How can I manage when the client is going to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By executing twice `response.body()` you try to consume the request body twice: once in the logging `LOG.info(String.format("Response data is: =[%s]", response.body().string()));` and once in the return statement `return response.body().string();`. According to the documentation it can only be consumed once:

> Returns a non-null value if this response was passed to {@link Callback#onResponse} or returned
>   from {@link Call#execute()}. Response bodies must be {@linkplain ResponseBody closed} and may
>   be consumed only once.
>   You can avoid this by saving it in a variable first and then use this variable, e.g.

```
final String requestBody = response.body().string();
LOG.info(String.format("Response data is: =[%s]", requestBody));
return requestBody;
```

Also you can replace try-catch by try-with-resources style, i.e.

```
try (Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
...
}
```